# grub appears to using the kernel insmod, is this possible?

Tags: grub2, kernel

I am trying to learn the GNU/Ubuntu-Linux in a detailed way.

I was reading 00_header, which run first when grub loads, and I saw

```
for i in ${GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES} ; do
  echo "insmod $i"
done
```

As I know, insmod is a module loader used by Kernel.
If the grub is running; there must be no Kernel loaded. How can this code run?

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooops!

Pardon me for that, but I just found it.

It is just a similarity of name.
I found it under /boot/grub/insmod

Comment: Indeed, grub has loadable modules in a similar fashion to the kernel often for similar things such as file system support.  The modules are completely unrelated however.